# Correct way to use pundit when access depends on parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a Client model which has_many Contacts

Whether a user can create, update or edit depends on the Client rather than the Contact whereas Destroy depends on the Contact itself.

In the ContactPolicy class I can simply check @contact.client to see if the user can have access which is fine.

However for the List method I do not have a single contact but a list of @client.contacts so there is no simple way to tell Pundit what to allow.

I'm not sure how Pundit is supposed to handle this.

Note that I dont want a Scope as it is either a yes or no depending on the Client record

Comment: I have started doing it by using something like    authorize(@client.contacts.build) in order to pass a contact that will enable the policy to check the client. But it seems a bit tacky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that since the access is determined by the client and *not* the contact, the determination should be in the `ClientPolicy` and *not* the `ContactPolicy`.

Pundit policies are simple ruby classes, and there's no rule that says the capability methods need to correspond to controller actions.  From your description, it sounds like the capability you're looking for is whether a client can `list_contacts?`.  So just write that capability and use it in the action instead of the default `index?`

```
class ContactsController
  def index
    # assuming you've determined the parent `@client` somehow
    authorize @client, :list_contacts?
    # ...
  end
end

class ClientPolicy
  def list_contacts?
    # your capability logic here
  end
end
```